# Java - Remove "Optional" from a variable (convert)

Tags: java, arraylist, option-type, data-conversion

for a piece of homework, I have to set a variable. The set method given to me, converts that into "Optional". However, I have to store this variable in an ArrayList which doesn't allow Optional variables.How can I convert the variable so it is no longer Optional?

The set method:

```
 public void setParentVertex(IVertex<T> parentVertex)
    {
    if(parentVertex == null)
        this.parentVertex = Optional.empty();
    else
        this.parentVertex = Optional.of(parentVertex);
}
```

Where I'm trying to use it:

```
 ArrayList<IVertex<T>> path = new ArrayList<IVertex<T>>();
 IVertex<T> parent = current.getLabel().getParentVertex();
 path.add(parent);
```

The error I keep receiving is: "Error: incompatible types: Optional> cannot be converted to IVertex" due to the line where I declare the variable "parent".
Thank you.

Comment: What should be stored in the list if the optional is empty? Have you read the javadoc of Optional? Why aren't you using Optional.ofNullable()? Note that using Optional as the type of a field is strongly discouraged. It's meant to be used as the return type of methods.

Comment: @JBNizet I'm afraid I didn't get to choose that. I have just been given code from my Lecturer and have been told to use that. Why he chose to use only "Optional", I have no idea.

Comment: That shouldn't prevent you from reading the documentation. After reading it, what you should do should become obvious.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the correct version

```
List<IVertex<T>> path = new ArrayList<IVertex<T>>();
current.getLabel().getParentVertex().ifPresent(path::add)
```

Also it would be good to rewrite `setParentVertex` function:

```
public void setParentVertex(IVertex<T> parentVertex) {
  this.parentVertex = Optional.ofNullable(parentVertex);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you don't have to add it to your list, if there is no value. So just do

```
if(nameOfOptional.isPresent()){
   list.add(nameOfOptional.get());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, **add a check to find the value is present or not** (by calling `isPresent()`) and then if the value is present then add to your `ArrayList` `path` object as shown below:

```
ArrayList<IVertex<T>> path = new ArrayList<>();
Optional<IVertex<T>> parent = current.getLabel().getParentVertex();
if(parent.isPresent()) {
    path.add(parent.get());
}
```

or the shorter form is shown below which uses `ifPresent` method:

```
ArrayList<IVertex<T>> path = new ArrayList<>();
Optional<IVertex<T>> parent = current.getLabel().getParentVertex();
parent.ifPresent(path::add);
```

Also, I suggest you have a look at the `Optional` API methods [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html).

As a side note, I recommend you to use diamond `<>` operator while declaring generic types (like shown above i.e., `new ArrayList<>()`) , so that your code will be less verbose.

Comment: You could make it shorter like
parent.ifPresent(path::add);

Comment: This worked! Thank you :) I'll keep that side note in mind as well.